# Using async await to defer execution of a block

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

In my Angular component I have created an async method that needs to do something after a method in the data service has returned some data.  I am trying to use async await but I don't think I have a good grasp of the concept.  Here is the method in the component I have tried to write:

```
async redrawGrid(params: any) {
        let v;
        try {
            v = await this.innerGridService.loadAccountList()
        } catch (error) {
            // return error
        }
        // I need to execute this code after loadAccountList() returns data
        params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight( (this.globalRowCount * 46 ) + 48);
        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```

The method in my service loadAccountList() returns and observable:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class ClientListService { 
...
responseObject$: Observable<ResponseObject>;
...

}
loadAccountList() {
        this.logService.info('InnerGridService loadAccountList()');

        if (this.dataStore.responseObject) {
            this.refreshDataStore();
        }
        let token = this.authenticationService.getToken();
        let headers = new Headers({ 'netx.esf.AuthenticationService': token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, options)
.map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(
            (data: InnerGridResponse) => {
                this.formatData(data.response.accountlist);
                this.dataStore.InnerGridResponse = data;
                this.dataStore.responseObject = data.response;
                this._InnerGridResponse.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).InnerGridResponse);
                this._responseObject.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).responseObject);
                if (data.errorCode === 0 || data.errorCode === 90) { // success
                    this.logService.info('loadAccountList() success: ', data.errorCode);
                    this.clearError();
                } else { // error code from backend
                    this.logService.error('loadAccountList() errorCode: ', data.errorCode);
                    this.setError(this.message[0], data.errorCode);
                }
            },
            error => { // exception
                this.logService.error('loadAccountList() exception:', error);
                this.setError(this.message[0], error._body);
                // throw error;
            });

        return this.responseObject$;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, async/await only works with promises, not Observables. I'm not sure where responseObject$ is defined, but it looks like it may be an Observable.

Comment: yes you also have to show the `this.http.get.subscribe` body

Comment: Updated to reflect.  Thank you.

Comment: This article: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875 Shows how to use the `defer` method of an Observable to interop correctly with async await

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me for saying this, but this code needs major rework.

You're committing the classic anti-pattern of taking data from one stream and putting it into another. It's like pouring water from a hose into a bucket, and then trying to pour water from the bucket into another hose. Instead, just connect the hoses, or better yet, just hand someone the hose you already have.

To oversimplify, a service in general should not subscribe and try to do anything with the observable. It should just return it, often after mapping. The subscribing should be done in the consumer (the component), either in the TS logic, or the template using the `async` pipe.

I'm not going to try rewrite your service, since there's too much going on there that I don't understand. The basic skeleton should be:

```
locaAccountList(): Proimse<AccountList> {
  return this.http.get(URL)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .toPromise()
    .then(json => makeAccountListFromJson(json));
}
```

I've rewritten this to return a promise instead of an observable, using `toPromise`. This is often seen with `this.http`, which typically returns an observable with just a single emission. That way, you can `await` the result. You can't `await` an observable to emit. `await` is for promises. Trying to `await` an observable will accomplish nothing more than `await 42`.

Once you've re-written your service, your component can just say:

```
async redrawGrid(params: any) {
  await this.innerGridService.loadAccountList();

  // I need to execute this code after loadAccountList() returns data
  params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight( (this.globalRowCount * 46 ) + 48);
  this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```

You (probably) don't need the `try` because errors in an async function will flow down out the bottom anyway and return a rejected promise from the function. By the way, it's not clear to me how you're using the result of calling `loadAccountList()`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am a junior developer and pointers like this are invaluable.  However, even if this code is far from optimal, it is still not clear to me why `await this.innerGridService.loadAccountList();` would not work...?  The method in my service returns an observable yes, so I could just try `await this.innerGridService.loadAccountList().toPromise();` correct?  This not not seem to work however...

Comment: `await` waits for a promise to resolve. It doesn't wait for an observable to emit.

Comment: Yes, I got that from your example and the documentation.  `loadAccountList()` needs to return a Promise, not an Observable as it currently is.  I plan to rewrite this method as you suggested, but just as a POC I wonder if I can just add `.toPromise()` on `await` `this.innerGridService.loadAccountList();` to make it work...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait to continue until data is retrieved, move the subscribe from the service into the redrawGrid and add the code to execute within the subscribe callback method.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I am very new at this so I would please ask if you could demonstrate in code.

Comment: I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple solution would be:

```
async redrawGrid(params: any) {
        let v;
        try {
            //notice .toPromise() part
            v = await this.innerGridService.loadAccountList().toPromise();
        } catch (error) {
            // return error
        }
        // I need to execute this code after loadAccountList() returns data
        params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight( (this.globalRowCount * 46 ) + 48);
        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```